# Why is R sorting my character vector incorrectly?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a bunch of character vectors of numbers like this one:

```
numbers_c <- c("8.76782130111354e-05", "0.1523", "0.4316", "6.80470451316959e-05","2.45", 
"5.29226369075514e-05", "6.123", "7.11446903389845e-05")
```

I want to sort them from biggest to smallest, so I use the built-in sort-function and get this:

```
> sort(numbers_c, decreasing = TRUE)
 [1] "8.76782130111354e-05" "7.11446903389845e-05" "6.80470451316959e-05"
 [4] "6.123"                "5.29226369075514e-05" "2.45"                
 [7] "0.4316"               "0.1523"
```

It seems like the sort-function doesn't get that the numbers with "e-05" are very small. How can I make it understand that?

Comment: Character vectors can only be sorted according to string collation. Turn them into numeric  vectors if you need numeric sorting.

Comment: Yes, why not `sort(as.numeric(numbers_c), decreasing = TRUE)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the character to numeric and use `order`.

```
numbers_c[order(as.numeric(numbers_c), decreasing = TRUE)]
#[1] "6.123"                "2.45"                 "0.4316"              
#[4] "0.1523"               "8.76782130111354e-05" "7.11446903389845e-05"
#[7] "6.80470451316959e-05" "5.29226369075514e-05"
```

Comment: Another option if you don't want to convert your data is gtools::mixedsort function, which handles this exact problem https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/mixedsort